# How to display/hide the footer, when Toast is opened/closed?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I need help with the following:
I would like for the footer to be displayed only when the toast is open. And when the toast dissapears, after a few seconds, the footer needs to come back.
Can someone help me? I am new to React.
The Toast is from bootstrap. It is working fine right now (shows and hides when it is suppose to). The state, etc for the toast is in redux.
Below is the code:

```
<Toast toastStore={toast} showToast={() => toast.open} />

{toast.open ? null : (
       <footer className="footer sticky-bottom bg-white d-flex align-items-center w-100">
            <div className={`row ${styles.footerRow}`}>
              <div className="col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start">
                <Link to="/employees">
                  <button
                    className={`btn btn-outline-dark ${styles.backButtton}`}
                  >
                    <ChevronLeft />
                    <span className="fw-bold fs-20">一覧に戻る</span>
                  </button>
                </Link>
              </div>
              <div className="col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
                <button
                  className={`btn btn-primary fw-bold fs-20 ${styles.registerButton}`}
                  type="submit"
                  onClick={handleForm}
                >
                  登録
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
       </footer>
)}
```

Any kind of workaround would be helpful.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a state to save the value of toast

```
const [isToastOpened,setIsToastOpened] = useState(false)
```

then use that value

```
<Toast toastStore={toast} showToast={isToastOpened} />

{!isToastOpened && () // your footer here
```

Also use setIsToastOpened to open and close your toast like

```
<Button onClick={()=> setIsToastOpened(true)}>Open toast</Button>
```